# Lightning Component Quick Action - Hide Modal Placeholder

Tags: lightning-quickaction, lightning-components

I've created a new lightning component - which suppose only to update certain fields - and notify the rep when it's completed (using toast event).

I added this as a quick action - and every time i'm clicking on the button, there's a placeholder which pop for a second (you can see on the attached image).

As I understand, this is a knows issue (https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000KS43QAG), but just wanted to know if anyone found a way to hide this placeholder, so it won't appear when the button is been pressed.

Thanks for the help !
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the closeQuickAction doesn't fire at all. By the time we doesn't have any better solution.
You can try this workaround:

```
setTimeout(() => {
            var element = document.getElementsByClassName("DESKTOP uiModal forceModal");    
            element.forEach(function(e, t) {
            $A.util.addClass(e, 'slds-hide');
        }); 
}, 3000);
```

This should close the toast automatically.

Comment: Hi Sachin,
Thanks for you response.
Unfortunately, this doesn't seems to solve the issue ..

Comment: Can you add more details how do you want it to be.

Comment: Of course.
Once you are clicking on the QA button - I want to show spinner (which I added to my component), but I don't want the placholder to be shown.
The actual behavior now is like that: i'm clicking on the QA, the placholder is been shown for a brief, after that the spinner shows - and then the toat event of the component. I just want to understand how can I hide the placeholder after i'm clicking on the button, and if it's even possible.